# Can't use Google's fonts properly

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, google-font-api

So I've been trying to import Google's fonts and integrate them into a website without success.

The CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Linden+Hill);
/*...*/
body.single-post p, body.page p{
    font-family: 'Linden Hill', sans-serif;
}
```

For some reason, when I try to use the font, in both Firefox and Google Chrome, it doesn't load/show the font, with or without quotation marks wrapped around the font name.

Google Fonts's website says that to include the font, you do this:

```
font-family: 'Linden Hill', serif;
```

...but it doesn't work.

Now, for a different font, Tangerine (note that it's one word), it works if I include it without quotation marks, like so

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine);
/*...*/
body.single-post p, body.page p{
    font-family: Tangerine, sans-serif;
}
```

...but if you do what Google Fonts tells you, and wrap it in single quotes, it magically stops working.

This is what it looks like in the inspector:

[image: Mom, I broke the website!]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the @import before any style rules in the document?  I know it is in your example here, but there's a whole load of styles before that in the inspector.

Comment: @davidpauljunior It's right after a few imports, [and a @font-face](http://i.imgur.com/4SKhEqY.png). I'll move it back further and see if it works.

Comment: @davidpauljunior Argh, a rookie mistake. Yeah, moving the `@import` before the `@font-face` definition fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  With the other example where Tangerine worked, I wondered if that font was on your machine already.

Comment: @davidpauljunior If you read the second half of the post, it shows that it essentially grabs it from Google Fonts as well.

Comment: I know, but as it wasn't working I wondered if the import was a red herring (wasn't actually working) but the font was showing when you didn't use quotation marks because it was on the machine.  Just a thought

Comment: @davidpauljunior Hmm, I do believe this computer has the font installed, maybe you're right. I'll take a look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had the @import after a @font-face definition.

```
/*some other @imports*/
@font-face {/*font face here*/}
@import url(/*the font URL here*/)
```

Moving it before the @font-face definition fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That should work with double quote:

> font-family: "Linden Hill", serif;

Comment: The issue is that, it doesn't. I tried all sorts of quotes, and all variations of it. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are doing wrong in css here (body.single-post p, body.page p),

see here if you are using directly like this.

```
body{
    font-family: 'Linden Hill', sans-serif ;
}
```

you need to write css tree
try this may it work

```
body .single-post p, body .page p{
    font-family: 'Linden Hill', sans-serif;
}
```

or if you can, show me the the code where you want to use it

its working fine the quotation make is not problem